# Embed custom view in android home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-controls, ads

I am building a home screen widget and I want to add an advertisement to it. Currently the advertises SDK provides a custom view widget which I tried to embed in my home screen widget. But when I add it, it says problem loading widget. I'm guessing I can't add custom views to a widget? Could someone clarify or tell me how I could add an advertisement to my home screen widget.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home screen widgets support very limited number of standard widgets. You can't use custom widgets for them. See [App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).